# Pdf Write and Read Itext

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm currently trying to create a pdf file then read it from my android device with the Itext library.

**My problem**
When I try to open the pdf view intent, my file doesn't exists, even though I tried seeing the path trough Toasts, which seemed perfectly fine...

Here's my code:

```
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException{


        pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "pdfdemo");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdir();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Pdf Directory created");
        }

        myFile = new File(pdfFolder + "/pdftest.pdf");
        /*String path = myFile.getPath();
        Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }


        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        //Step 1
        Document document = new Document();

        //Step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

        //Step 3
        document.open();

        //Step 4 Add content
        document.add(new Paragraph(edt_email.getText().toString()));
        document.add(new Paragraph(edt_name.getText().toString()));

        //Step 5: Close the document
        document.close();

    }
```

My code is from Val Okafor from his Itext example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986574/Android-iText-Pdf-Example

And here's the way I'm trying to open it:

```
private void viewPdf(){

        /*String filepath = myFile.getPath();
        Toast.makeText(this, filepath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        if (myFile.exists()) {

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            Toast.makeText(this, "File exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "file doesnt exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

(I have added the permissions to read and write to external storage)

Where did I go wrong? Please help my out with this,
Have a good day/evening/night!

Comment: `pdfFolder.mkdir();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Pdf Directory created");` You are too optimistic as you should check the return value of mkdir(). Only if it returns true you can display that Toast(). And if it returns false you should display a different toast. And immedeately return as it does not make sense then to continue.

Comment: `try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
`. There is no need to create an empyty file there. But if you do you should place a Toast() in that catch block. And then return. As it again does not make sense to continue if that catch happens.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "file doesnt exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`. Change to: `Toast.makeText(this, "file doesnt exist: " + myFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }`